# Type erasure, generics and existential types

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have a `List` of a parametric type, `List[Field[_]]`, and I want something like this:

```
sealed trait FieldType[K] { val name: String }
sealed trait StringField extends FieldType[String]
case object publisher extends StringField { val name = "publisher" }
// ...

trait Field[K] {
  val field: FieldType[K]
  val value: K
}

case class Publisher(value: String) extends Field[String] { val field = publisher }
// ...

def get[K](l: List[Field[_]], key: FieldType[K]) : Option[K] =
  l match {
  case Nil => None
  case (a:Field[K]) :: rest  => Some(a.value)
  case (a:Field[_]) :: rest => get(rest, key)
}
```

which doesn't work, because K is erased. I tried typetags, but I must confess I got lost. Any quick way to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use type tags to get the compiler to generate the erased type information. According to the [Scala documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) there are three ways to optain a tag.

By adding an implicit evidence parameter of type `ClassTag`, the compiler will generate the missing type information if it cannot find a suitable implicit value. Given the evidence, we can obtain the runtime class and compare it to the runtime class of the `value` of your `Field`.

```
def get[A](l: List[Field[_]])(implicit evidence: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] =
  l match {
    case Nil => None
    case (a: Field[A]) :: rest if evidence.runtimeClass == a.value.getClass =>
      Some(a.value)
    case a :: rest =>
      get[A](rest)
  }
```

However, note that in this example, `get[Int]` will produce a `ClassTag` with the runtime class `Int` whereas `value.getClass` will return a `java.lang.Integer`

Given `case class Other(value: Int) extends Field[Int]`, this will yield the following result:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(get[String](Other(4) :: Other(2) :: Publisher("foo") :: Nil)) // Some(foo)
  println(get[Integer](Other(4) :: Other(2) :: Publisher("foo") :: Nil)) // Some(4)
  println(get[Int](Other(4) :: Other(2) :: Publisher("foo") :: Nil)) // None
}
```

Note that I removed the parameter `key`, as it did not serve a purpose. If the key is supposed to be unique, then, instead of checking the type tag, I would suggest matching against the key, thereby not using reflection:

```
def get[A](l: List[Field[_]], key: FieldType[A]): Option[A] = l match {
  case Nil => None
  case a :: rest if a.field == key => Some(a.value.asInstanceOf[A])
  case a :: rest => get(rest, key)
}
```

### Edit: To address your questions from the comments:

#### is the asInstanceOf necessary? ... I was under the impression that having to resort to it is sort of bad practice/to be avoided/unsafe. Is that correct?

Since `l` is of type `List[Field[_]]`, `a` is of type `Field[_]`, meaning that `a.value` has the existential type, i.e., the compiler does not know it is of type `A`. However, because of the relation between `a.key` and `a.value`, we know that if `a.field` is of type `FieldType[A]`, then `value` is of type `A`, so this particular type cast is safe (as long as you do not change the code).

You are absolutely correct that having to use a type cast indicates a flaw in the design, so maybe the best solution is to redesign `Field`, or the list `l`. Actually, I'd ask myself why you need to put various different types of `Field` in a list and then extract a certain type of `Field` later on? Maybe `List` is the wrong data structure? Would a `Map[FieldType[_], List[Field[_]]` be a better choice to store your fields? Or a `Map[Class[_], List[Field[_]]`? Or maybe a custom data structure?

Note that you can get rid of the `asInstanceOf` in the following way:

```
def get[A](l: List[Field[_]], key: FieldType[A]): Option[A] = l match {
  case Nil => None
  case (a: Field[A]) :: rest if a.field == key => Some(a.value)
  case a :: rest => get(rest, key)
}
```

but this does not give you more static safety, because type erasure makes `Field[A]` match against any generic version of `Field`. I'd say this variant is worse because it makes the explicit type cast implicit, hence this code is more error prone.

#### I was trying to use TypeTag[] and typeOf[] instead of ClassTag and runtimeClass, as those where the example I found on the documentation page you linked (and elsewhere). What's the difference? Most of all, I want information regarding the _ in Field[_], so why oh why the ClassTag is on A?!?

There are three type tags that were introduced as a replacement for `Manifest`:

- `TypeTag`
- `WeakTypeTag`
- `ClassTag`

From the [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.ClassTag):

> ClassTags are a weaker special case of scala.reflect.api.TypeTags#TypeTags, in that they wrap only the runtime class of a given type, whereas a TypeTag contains all static type information.

While you could probably also solve the problem using `TypeTag`, I figured that it suffices to compare the runtime class.

The problem is that the existential type can really be any superclass of `A`, because the list `l` can contain all kinds of `Field`s. In the example I gave, we have a list of `Field[Int] :: Field[Int] :: Field[String] :: Field[Int]`, hence the existential type in this case must be `Any`, the least common supertype of `Int` and `String`. In other words: You benefit nothing from deriving the existential type of `l: List[Field[_]]`.

However, what you actually want to do is find the first element in the list whose `value` is of type `A`. Because `A` is erased, the only way to obtain information about its runtime type is by passing the information as an additional argument, e.g., using the implicit `ClassTag` evidence. Now all that remains is finding out which element has a value of the corresponding type, hence `a.value.getClass == evidence.runtimeClass`.

Comment: I cannot do without the key in my case, but you are right, thank you! In this case I don't even need all that machinery...
Two questions, if I may:
- is the `asInstanceOf` necessary? I tried without, and it works fine. (and if it is necessary, I was under the impression that having to resort to it is sort of bad practice/to be avoided/unsafe. Is that correct?)

Comment: And:
- I was trying to use `TypeTag[]` and `typeOf[]` instead of `ClassTag` and `runtimeClass`, as those where the example I found on the documentation page you linked (and elsewhere). What's the difference? Most of all, I want information regarding the `_` in `Field[_]`, so why oh why the `ClassTag` is on `A`?!?

Comment: @kenshin Thank you for your feedback. I tried to address your questions by editing the answer.